# Continuity of real function(real analysis)

Tags: analysis

If $f, g: R\to R$ is continuous at a point $c$, let $h(x):= \sup\{f(x), g(x)\}$ for $x \in R$. Show that $$h(x)=\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{2}+\frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{2}$$ for all $x \in R$. Use this to show that $h$ is continuous at $c$.

How do I show it?

Comment: the sum of two continuous functions is continuous

Comment: Two cases: If $f(x)\geq g(x)$ then $|f(x)-g(x)|=f(x)-g(x)$. Simplify the expression above, which will result in $f(x)$. If $f(x)<g(x)$ then $|f(x)-g(x)|=g(x)-f(x)$. Simplifying the expression gives $g(x)$.

Comment: The key is that "absolute value".  If a> b then |a- b|= a- b.  If b> a then |a- b|= b- a.  So if a> b then (1/2)(a+ b)- (1/2)|a- b|= (1/2)(a+ b)+ (1/2)(a- b)= a and if b> a then (1/2)(a+ b)- (1/2)|a- b|= (1/2)(a+ b)+ (1/2)(b- a)= b.

Answer (score 0):

For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $h(x) = \sup\{f(x),g(x)\}$.
Fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have 3 cases:

1) $f(x)=g(x)$

In this case, $f(x) - g(x) = 0$. Moreover, $h(x)=\dfrac{f(x)}{2}+\dfrac{f(x)}{2}=\dfrac{f(x)}{2}+\dfrac{g(x)}{2}$. Then:

$$
h(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}[f(x)+g(x)] =\dfrac{1}{2}[f(x)+g(x)] + \dfrac{1}{2}[|f(x)-g(x)|]
$$

2) $f(x)>g(x)$

In this case, $|f(x)-g(x)| = f(x) - g(x)$. Moreover, $h(x)=f(x)$. Note that:

$$
\dfrac{1}{2}[f(x)+g(x)] + \dfrac{1}{2}[|f(x)-g(x)|] = \dfrac{1}{2}[f(x)+g(x)] + \dfrac{1}{2}[f(x)-g(x)] = \dfrac{f(x)}{2}+\dfrac{f(x)}{2} = f(x)=h(x)
$$

3) $f(x)<g(x)$

In this case, $|f(x)-g(x)| = g(x) - f(x)$. Moreover, $h(x)=g(x)$. Note that:

$$
\dfrac{1}{2}[f(x)+g(x)] + \dfrac{1}{2}[|f(x)-g(x)|] = \dfrac{1}{2}[f(x)+g(x)] + \dfrac{1}{2}[g(x)-f(x)] = \dfrac{g(x)}{2}+\dfrac{g(x)}{2} = g(x)=h(x)
$$

What proves equality for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Continuity follows the continuity of f and g and the module function

Comment: Why sup{f(x),g(x)}=max{f(x),g(x)}???

Comment: You can always compare $ f $ and $ g $, and then you can set the maximum between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ values. The maximum of one set coincides with the supreme